# Not in clause postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

table1

```
  emp_id     Grade

   1     first_class
   2     Second_class
   3     first_class
   4     third_class
```

table2

```
emp_id     Grade

   1        A
   2        B
   3        A
   4        C
```

In table 2 we have grades column values that are transformed

eg

if first_class then A

if Second_class then B

if third_class then C

How to write a query that is similar to below

```
select * from table1 where
emp_id||Grade not in (select emp_id||Grade from table2);
```

the above query doesn't work because in one of the table values of Grade column values are transformed.

Comment: what mean binned? and what is your expected result?

Comment: in the above example i mentioned the result will be zero.Binned mean the grade column values  are transformed to A,B,C

Comment: I check again and dont see anything similar to desire output,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use tuples:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where (emp_id, grade) not in (select emp_id,
                                     (case Grade when 'first_class' then 'A'
                                                 when 'Second_class' then 'B'
                                                 when 'third_class' then 'C'
                                                 else ''
                                      end)
                              from table2
                             );
```

Note that `NOT IN` this makes me nervous because of how it works with `NULL` values.  For that reason, I included an empty string for the `ELSE`.

Postgres supports tuples, so there is no need for concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you finding something like below sql

```
 select * from table1 where
     concat(emp_id,
   case Grade when 'first_class' then 'A'
              when 'Second_class' then 'B'
               when 'third_class' then 'C' end) not in 
   (select concat(emp_id,Grade) from table2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from table1 
where  emp_id||Grade not in (select emp_id || CASE Grade 
                                              WHEN 'A' THEN 'first_class'
                                              WHEN 'B' THEN 'Second_class'
                                              WHEN 'C' THEN 'third_class'
                                              END
                             from table2);
```